# redirecting to youtube to upload video available on jsp

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, video, youtube

I have a jsp page that shows videos and user can play that videos. Now I a need to keep an youtube icon so that upon clicking that icon user can be redirected to youtube and it should ask for login and after login that video should be started uploading. I tried a lot of googling and looked at [link1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) , [link2](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/), and [link3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) but couldn't figure it out to work with.
Any suggestion/help will be appriciated :)

Comment: I have no idea how to start with, like whether I need to implement the code for uploading or Youtube API will take care of it. For fb, Pinterest etc it was quite simple, just needed to pass the URL of video and few other parametes. :(

Comment: Here you have an example of java code that uploads the video. I don't know if that's what you want, but it doesn't seem too complicated. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Uploading_Videos

Comment: `For fb, Pinterest etc it was quite simple`  - please explain in detail, what exactly did you implemented with FB & Pinterest ? Or is it just page-url sharing ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

1. [Uploading videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Uploading_Videos)
2. [Enabling user interaction](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Enabling_user_interaction)